# Phonological rule for realizations of Italian /s/

Tags: phonology, italian

It seems that realization of [Italian /s/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography#S_and_Z) is not fully systematic and there are some exceptions. Is there any [phonological rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_rule) for possible realizations of Italian /s/

Comment: [Italian s-voicing and the structure of the phonological word](http://www.vanoostendorp.nl/fonologie/italian.html)

Answer (score 4):

While [the link in ukemi's comment](http://www.vanoostendorp.nl/fonologie/italian.html) gives a good description of the rules governing S-voicing, the main question here has a simple answer.

**/s/ and /z/ are separate phonemes in (standard/Tuscan) Italian.**

This is shown by (near-)minimal pairs such as *cosa* `/ko.sa/` "matter" and *sposa* `/spo.za/` "bride". Both of these come directly from single Latin words, so the rules laid down by Oostendorp don't apply.

(EDIT: Michaelyus has provided a true minimal pair: *presento* `/pre.zɛn.to/` "I present" versus *presento* `/pre.sɛn.to/` "I foresee". Much obliged!)

In many environments, this distinction is neutralized: in fact, everywhere except between vowels within a single mono-morphemic word. In most dialects it's even neutralized in this environment—in the north they merge into /z/, while in the south they merge into /s/. So in the (relatively) near future, Italian will likely have only a single dental sibilant phoneme, just as Latin did.

Comment: I would call cosa ~ sposa a near-minimal pair.

Comment: @fdb Fixed, ty!

Comment: @sumelic Oops, of course, also <z>.

Comment: A well-known _true_ minimal pair is _presento_ (from _presentire_ = /s/, from _presentare_ = /z/).